# From metric to topological vector space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that $E = C[0,1]$ and suppose we have a metric given by 
$$d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \min(|f(x)-g(x)|,1)dx$$
Why is it that the topology defined by this metric makes $E$ into a topological vector space?

On the same topic, suppose that $\tau_p$ is defined by the seminorms $f \mapsto |f(x)|, x \in [0,1]$, why is the mapping $$\iota: (E, \tau_p) \rightarrow (E,d) \quad f \mapsto \iota(f)$$
is sequentially continous? To put it in other words, if a sequence in $\tau_p$ convergent it is $d$ convergent.
Also, why is $\iota$ not continuous?

Comment: This is not a metric on $C[0,1].$ consider $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x^3.$ Then $d(f,g)=0$ while $f\not=g.$

Comment: This is not true, because for those $f(x),g(x)$ we have $\min (|f(x)-g(x)|) = f(x) - g(x)$ which does not integrate to zero on $[0,1]$.

Comment: what do you mean by $\min(|f(x) - g(x)|)$? I mean, it's just $\min(a) = a$

Comment: I see that i made a mistake in the definition. But I fixed it!

Comment: You should first convince yourself that convergence w.r.t. $d$ is the same as convergence in measure. Then, note that convergence w.r.t. $\tau_p$ is pointwise convergence. Using dominated convergence, you can show that this implies convergence w.r.t $d$ **for sequences**, so that $\iota$ is sequentially continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The topology is generated by sets of the form
$$
U_{f,r}=\{g\in C[0,1]: d(\,f,g)<r\}=f+\{g\in C[0,1]: d(0,g)<r\}.
$$
Note that
$$
U_{0,r}+U_{0,r}\subset U_{0,2r}.
$$

It suffices to show that
$$
(\lambda,f)\longmapsto \lambda f,\quad\text{and}\quad
(f,g)\longmapsto f+g,
$$
are continuous. with respect to above topology.

a. If $f+g\in V$, $V\subset C[0,1]$ open, then $f+g\in U_{f+g,r}\subset U$, for some $r>0$, and
$$
U_{f,r/2}+U_{g,r/2}\subset U_{f+g,r}\subset V,
$$
and hence $(f,g)\mapsto f+g$ continuous.

b. Continuity of $(\lambda,f)\mapsto \lambda f$ is also straight-forward, starting first with the case $\lambda=0$.

Comment: And even if it were equivalent to the $L^2$ metric, this doesn't answer the question (why does this metric or the $L^2$ one make it into a topological vector space).